# Replacing any occurances of an object name with the object value

Tags: javascript, jquery

So far I have this which replaces the text in the input box if it has the object name in it, with the object value:

```
var obj = {
    '1': 'fish',
    'q': 'apple',
    'z': 'banana',
};

$("#inputBoxID").on("keyup", function() {
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty($("#inputBoxID").val())) $(this).val(obj[$("#inputBoxID").val()]);
});
```

I would like to modify this so that on any occurrence of a object name it would replace the object name with the value, here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

User enters `hello q` I want that to be replaced with: `hello apple`

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: what should happen if user type 'qq'?

Comment: or if user type 'hello question1'? Should it replace q,e, and 1?

Comment: @yajiv it would turn into `appleapple`

Comment: @Observer yes it should

Comment: @newbie there is 'e' in apple, it should replace or not?(means if i write apple then what would be the output)

Comment: @yajiv That was just for an example, please see the updated edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply replace any occurrence of key with it's value, like below(I know it's little heavy as for each key press we are iterating through object).

```js
var obj = {
    '1': 'fish',
    'q': 'apple',
    'z': 'banana',
};

$("#inputBoxID").on("keyup", function() {
  var str = $("#inputBoxID").val();
  for(var x in obj){
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty(x)){
      str=str.replace(x,obj[x]);
    }
  }
  $(this).val(str);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="inputBoxID" type="text">
```

Answer (score 2):

You can split by space, map and then join!

```js
var obj = {    '1': 'fish',    'q': 'apple',    'e': 'banana'};

$("#inputBoxID").on("keyup", function() {
  var str = $("#inputBoxID").val().split(' ').map(function(word) {
    return obj[word] || word;    
  }).join(' ');
  $(this).val(str);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="inputBoxID">
```

Comment: I can not write any word that starts with q or e or 1

Comment: I didnt ask the question bro. Just was an observation

Comment: Thanks @Ele how can I modify this so that if someone entered `qq` it would change into `appleapple` ?

Comment: Do you want to replace every letter who matches with any key in obj?

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna replace each word separately by splitting the string into an array of words and then replacing it:

```
  $("#inputBoxID").val((_, v) => v.split(" ").map(word => obj[word] || word).join(" "))
```